# How to replace all occurences of a variable in a string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace all the occurrences of a variable in a string using javascript.

This is not working.:

```
var id = "__1";
var re = new RegExp('/' + id + '/g');
var newHtml = oldHtml.replace( re, "__2");
```

This is only replacing the first occurrence of id:

```
var id = "__1";
var newHtml = oldHtml.replace( id,"__2");
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you instantiate the RegExp object, you don't need to use slashes; the flags are passed as a second argument.  For example:

```
var id = "__1";
var re = new RegExp(id, 'g');
var newHtml = oldHtml.replace( re, "__2");
```

Comment: This won't work if there are regex characters in `id`

Answer (score 0):

You need the slashes before and after the string to replace (id).

[Example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)